# Searching for sizes in DB, half and full sizes

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to search through my database for sizes. Some are for clothing items in the following formats:

Small - Black
Small - Red

or

Small
Medium
Large
XL

The part of my query that searches for size is `LIKE '".$size."%'`  $size being Small, Medium, Large, or XL. This all works well. However I also need to search by shoe size. The problem is if I search for a size 10, it will return size 10 and size 10.5 results.

I was thinking I could do an if statement before the query to see if $size is a number and then have a different query for strings and numbers but I was looking for a cleaner way to do this. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: A shoe size should probably be a `DECIMAL` field so you can also do queries like `size > 8 AND size < 10`

Comment: Does the same column store both the numeric size (10, 10.5 etc) as well as the String size (Small, Medium, Large, XL etc)?

Comment: I can't think of a constructive comment that doesn't start with "ha ha" and ends with something about bit bucket, so I vote Pekka instead!

Comment: Nishant: Yes, those are in the same column

Answer (score 1):

Try the following where clause

```
size LIKE '".$size."%' AND size NOT LIKE '".$size.".5%'
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the column with [enum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)

sizes are defined (S,M,L,XL,XXL,XXXL,5,5.5,6,6.5,7....) is definitely fit into **65,535 elements**

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you can just use an "=" instead of a like? If you are then you'll get your XL, Medium or '10' hits back, don't you? Why not use `='".$size."'`

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers here all add up to one thing: you have a field full of random data.

The real answer is to come up with a way to formalize the data entry so you have uniformity. There are many ways to do this, but you might want to have an field enumerated as mentioned by ajreal for "plain language" style sizes (and CONSTRAIN data entry to this list), and a field for numeric sizes, and possibly a control field to indicate which one is to be used for the record. This example may not even be a good way, but you need to get the data uniform to make searches work efficiently.

A shortcut might be to whittle down the size by saying "like 'foo' or like '10.5'" which will return a subset of records and then iterating through and eliminate special case items upon display. This is a bad idea hack.